# Correlation id: unknown paypal payment integration

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying implement a server integration with the PayPal-PHP-SDK. When pressing the PayPal button this is called create-payment api . and when $payment->create($apiContext); is executed consolee shows an error -**

```php
Route::post('create-payment',function (){

    $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            'AUxYffBkrIrNeBizbjL9K7_XvlxTSeRnsWx_Uq6xJYZ66QsB00AiGvvZRuTIIJ1XqXEvjo8S4X9zSm-5',     // ClientID
            'ELLhNBC11ecv0yNP27nss5Z5VVHxAhqhGFfyzAn21y5V0a2QWRODVATxC5xSOE08MUDkSPMwY1JhGRkf'      // ClientSecret
        )
    );

    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    $item1 = new Item();
    $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        ->setPrice(7.5);
    $item2 = new Item();
    $item2->setName('Granola bars')
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(5)
        ->setSku("321321") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        ->setPrice(2);

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems(array($item1, $item2));

    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping(1.2)
        ->setTax(1.3)
        ->setSubtotal(17.50);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
        ->setTotal(20)
        ->setDetails($details);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());


    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout?success=true")
        ->setCancelUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout?success=false");

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $request = clone $payment;

    $payment->create($apiContext);



});
```

I called this code from route/api.php page.so there is no csrf issue.
When I'm going to execute create payment API PayPal modal is return with this error correlation id unknown, I haven't any idea about this error. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what specifically is going wrong without seeing the full, exact error details as well as code for the PayPal button you are using.

However, the PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated and uses a deprecated v1/payments API, so I can tell you about the integration you should be doing instead using the current `Checkout-PHP-SDK` for v2/checkout/orders

---

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server